# SVG backgrounds randomly doesn't show. Comes back after a certain time

Tags: javascript, css, svg, raspberry-pi

I'm running a website which randomly (?) doesn't show my SVG backgrounds. 
If I just leave it be it starts working again after an hour or so. Don't know how often this happens, but I guess a couple of times a day or so.

**The website:**
A javascript runs in the background and picks a CSS  depending on time of day.

```
<script>
<!--
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/morning.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/day.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 21) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/evening.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getStylesheet();
-->
</script>

<noscript><link href="css/day.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
```

The 4 CSS'es defines which SVG background to choose.

The CSS-files are like this. The only things that change are the CSS-filenames and the SVG-files.

```
body{
    background: #BDC3C7;
    background-image: url("/bilder/day.svg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Server**
Apache2

**Hardware**
Raspberry Pi 3

**Stuff I've tried**
At first I figured that it had something to do with Apache and switched to Nginx. Same exact problem on Nginx.

I then thought that the SVGs must be partially corrupted, and switched them out with four copies of a file I found on the net (http://www.spriteland.com/sprites/downloads/night-background_SVG.svg) renamed to day.svg, night.svg, evening.svg and morning.svg. Didn't help.

**Possible reasons why this happens:**

Something to do with the CSS
Something to do with the Javascript
Something do do with the Raspberry Pi.

Regarding the Raspberry Pi: 
It doesn't have a Real Time Clock. I'm uncertain about how it goes about to check which time it us (the machine I'm viewing the site on, or a clock on the internet somewhere). Timezone is set to Europe/Oslo.

If I just let it be, the website will display the svgs in an hour or so, but I would like to figure out what's causing the randomness of not displaying the SVGs. I'm at at loss...

I think I have ruled out the server software since I've tried both Nginx and Apache, and the SVGs-files themselves.

Comment: For currentTime = 21 your function does not write a stylesheet; third condition is `...currentTime < 21`, fourth condition is `22 <= currentTime...`

Comment: Thanks, man! I was able to solve the issue with your help :)